# Use 2 backend servers with different sticky session header in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

```
frontend application
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  use_backend mybackend1 if { req.hdr(my-User)}
  use_backend mybackend2 if { req.hdr(X-Hash)}

backend mybackend1
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  server Cont1 cont1:8000 check
  server Cont2 cont2:8000 check
  stick-table type string size 1m expire 10m
  stick on req.hdr(my-User)

backend mybackend2
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  server Cont3 cont3:9000 check
  server Cont4 cont4:9000 check
  stick-table type string size 1m expire 10m
  stick on req.hdr(X-Hash)
```

I use this haproxy.cfg file. And want to use different backend servers with different headers. Is there an issue in the if condition in the frontend section?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank You, it is solved, Task was to use a backend server using header info.
It should be like this:
use_backend mybackend1 if { req.hdr(my-User) -m found}